# Trying to insert date time into sql with variables in the query

Tags: mysql

```
String query = "insert into course_data 
                values (null, '" 
                        + CourseName + "','"
                        + SCrsDesrpTemp + "','" 
                        + CrsDes + "','" 
                        + crsurl + "','" 
                        + youtube + "','" 
                        + sqlStrDate + "','" 
                        + crsduration + "','" 
                        + CrsImg + "','" 
                        + category + "'," 
                        + "'Open2Study', 
                           '0.00', 
                           'English', 
                           'Yes','" 
                        + CrsImgUni + "','"  
                        + "GETDATE()" + "')";
```

That is my attempt above. I am trying to insert the current date and time into a date-time column but I keep getting syntax error for the query. It says GETDATE() is not the correct datatype for the column date-time.

Comment: `Mysql` <> `Sql Server` choose one

Comment: what language are you coding with ?

Comment: something looks odd at the `+ category + ...` line?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Sql Server:-

```
ALTER TABLE course_data ADD CONSTRAINT
DF_MyTable_Inserted DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR crsduration 
GO
```

This assumes your table is named course_data, the column is crsduration, and the name of the contstraint is to be DF_MyTable_Inserteddb in

If db in MySQL `NOW()` for get current date time

```
NOW()//Current date time
CURDATE()//Current date
```

Comment: But how would I go about doing that? I have 16 columns in the data table and I would need 16 values in the query